# Have I compromised my security because of unpacking an installation archive?

Tags: filesystem, security, tor

I'm NOT a technical person. I use only Ubuntu 14.04 lts on my computer, no other OS. Today I downloaded a package called 'Tor browser bundle' (tor-browser-linux64-5.0.2_en-US.tar.xz) from Tor-website to an empty folder called 'Current folder' and extracted it with Ubuntu's Archive Manager without using terminal. Now, even after extracting thrice I can't find extracted folder anywhere except enlisted in Archive Manager's window which also shows its location as '/', so I searched in '/' or Computer folder but couldn't find it there too. Later on I learnt that for security reasons that package shouldn't be unpacked or run as root. As I'm not a technical guy, I don't even know if I extracted it as root.

For your info: It didn't ask for any password while extracting. I have only one password I use for logging onto computer & while installing some Ubuntu software updates. One of the folders in Computer folder called 'root' doesn't open (I'm not complaining) saying "you do not have permissions necessary". So, where do I find the extractions and whether I extracted them as root? Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Do not worry you have not compromised your security. You simply extracted your package at the root of your hard drive. If you open "Computer" in your file browser, a `Tor browser bundle` should be here. Simply delete it :) Next time it probably be better for you to right click on your archive and select `Extract here`.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with " after extracting thrice I can't find extracted folder anywhere"; where did you drag and drop the content of the archive? That's where the extracted folder / files reside

Comment: Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: `sudo updatedb && locate -i tor`. You will find the path of the files.

Comment: you have not compromised security yet, but if you continue to run things as root, from outside the ubuntu repositories, without understanding what you are doing, eventually you will.

Comment: kos, when I couldn't find the extracted folder, I extracted again & then once again for same reason, hoping it will show up somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

A few points to make based on your post:

- It doesn't look like you've run anything as root. It would have asked for a password.
- Running things as root isn't *automatically* evil...
- ...Just as things can be insecure (and ruin your day) when not run as root.

You've just not been able to find where this has extracted to. You haven't really run anything new. **You are probably no less secure than before you did whatever it is you did.**

I'd suggest following [the given instructions](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux) *to the letter* instead of deviating and using Archive Manager... Well obviously not to the exact letter because you have to replace `LANG` with `en-US`... But you know what I mean.

If whatever you were doing extracted anything, it would have created a directory called `tor-browser_en-US`. You can find this:

```
find / -type d -name 'tor-browser_en-US' 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: The issue is - where did the extracted folder go each time - their location? (I extracted thrice). And even if I can't find them, is there anything else I should do now?

Comment: If they extracted anywhere (you may not have had permission) it would have created certain files and directories that you can now search for fairly trivially. I've added to my answer.

Comment: Also even if you extracted the archive 3 times using the same method each time, it may have written to the same location, overwriting the previously extracted files.